# how do i register global query in template

Tags: query, globals

ok i think this is a basic php question but here goes:

i have this working code:

```
  <!-- show the bands playing -->
                              <?php $child_posts = types_child_posts('my-intermediary');
                                foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
                                $band_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($child_post->ID,'album');
                                    $band = get_post($band_id);
                                    echo $band->post_title;
                                    echo $band->the_post_thumbnail();



                                   }
                                ?>
```

what I want to do is access the $band->post_title;  any where on the page so i'm guessing i need to cue this up globally on the page? adding this query to the header? 
so i would like to use some thing like `<?php echo $band(post_title); ?>`  < example

i hope that makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an array at the start of your layout, or in your functions file depending on the scope required and populate the array with all the bands using get_posts and making the key the post ID.

You will then have a global array of bands, and can pull info from each one wherever you need it.

some similar code from something I worked on:

```
global $bands;

$bands = array();
$bandPosts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'lmfBand', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title'));
foreach($bandPosts as $bandPost) {
    $bands["{$bandPost->ID}"] = array($bandPost->post_title,$bandPost->post_name);
}
```

then to get the band name, just use: $bands["{band_id}"][0] (in the version above)

You could also make each band a stdClass object instead of just an array of values.